# How to login into Facebook/Twitter programatically?

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-graph-api, oauth, cron

I am assigned to come up with a plan where an user can access facebook/twitter/emails through mobile SMS (offline). Here an offline user text his credentials to mobile network operator who in turn make a request to our application(rails) with given credentials to get the requested information of the user in text. My basic doubt is there a way to login into facebook/twitter/emails programatically ?

One alternative is to use Nokogiri like tools to send a post request. But I feel this is not a good idea. Please can anyone suggest on this ? Any APIs for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout rubys Net::Http library, most basic way to do that 
http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/ruby/online/ruby-doc-stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html

Apart from that there are loads of gems available, like

1. **facebooker** gem for interacting with Facbook API  http://rubygems.org/gems/facebooker
2. **Twitter** gem https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter